# The last enumerate item not aligning

Tags: enumerate, alignment

does anybody know why the last item (and items added after the 7th.) is not aligned with the previous items? I don't understand...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\title{Unit 1 Assessment, Part 2}
\date{May 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
  \item x - intercepts of the quadratic function $f(x)=-x^{2}+7x-6$ is at: \\
  $0 = -x^{2} + 7x - 6 = (x - 1)(-x + 6) \\
  x = 1,x = 6$ \\
  The vertical asymptotes of the reciprocal function $g(x)=\frac{1}{-x^{2}+7x-6}$: \\
  $x = 1,x = 6$ \\
  \\
  The horizontal asymptote of the reciprocal is y = 0  since all reciprocal functions have a horizontal asymptote at y = 0. \\
  \\
  The interval of increase of the quadratic function is $(-\infty,3.5)$, and the interval of decrease of the quadratic function is $(3.5,\infty)$. Therefore, the interval of decrease of the reciprocal function is $(-\infty,1)\cup(1,3.5)$, and the interval of increase of the reciprocal function is $(3.5,6)\cup(6,\infty)$.\\
  \\
  The quadratic function has a maximum point at x = 3.5, therefore the reciprocal has a minimum point at x = 3.5. \\
  \\
  The positive interval of the quadratic function is (1,6), and the negative interval of the quadratic function is $(-\infty,1)\cup(6,\infty)$. Therefore, the positive interval of the reciprocal function is (1,6), and the negative interval of the quadratic function is $(-\infty,1)\cup(6,\infty)$.\\
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{unit1part2a.png}
    \caption{Graph: $f(x)=-x^{2}+7x-6$ \& $g(x)=\frac{1}{-x^{2}+7x-6}$.}
  \end{figure}

  \item \begin{enumerate}
    \item $f(x) = \frac{-2x - 5}{3x + 18}$
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          Vertical asymptotes & Horizontal asymptotes & x - intercept & y - intercept & Domain \\
          \hline
          x = -6 & $y =  -\frac{2}{3}$ & $(-\frac{5}{2},0)$ & $(0,-\frac{5}{18})$ & $D = \{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\neq-6\}$ \\
          \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{unit1part2b.png}
      \caption{Graph: $f(x) = \frac{-2x - 5}{3x + 18}$.}
    \end{figure}

    \item Positive interval: $(-6,-2.5)$ \\
     Negative intervals: $(-\infty,-6)\cup(-2.5,\infty)$
  \end{enumerate}

  \item Find the real roots of the following rational equations.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\frac{-7x}{9x + 11} - 12 = \frac{1}{x} \\
    \frac{-7x}{9x + 11} = \frac{1 + 12x}{x} \\
    (-7x)(x) = (9x + 11)(1 + 12x) \\
    -7x^2 = 9x + 108x^2 + 11 + 132x \\
    115x^2 + 141x + 11 = 0 \\
    x = \frac{-141\pm\sqrt{141^2 - (4)(115)(11)}}{(2)(115)} \\
    x \approx -0.08,x \approx -1.14$

    \item $\frac{x - 1}{x + 2} = \frac{3x + 8}{5x - 1} \\
    (x - 1)(5x - 1) = (x + 2)(3x + 8) \\
    5x^2 - x - 5x + 1 = 3x^2 + 8x + 6x + 16 \\
    2x^2 - 20x - 15 = 0 \\
    x = \frac{-(-20)\pm\sqrt{(-20)^2 - (4)(2)(-15)}}{(2)(2)} \\
    x = \frac{10\pm\sqrt{130}}{2}$
  \end{enumerate}

  \item $8x - 3 \leq 2x+1 \leq 17x - 8 \\
  8x - 3 \leq 2x+1 \\
  6x \leq 4 \\
  x \leq \frac{2}{3} \\
  2x+1 \leq 17x - 8 \\
  9 \leq 15x \\
  x \geq \frac{3}{5} \\
  \frac{3}{5} \leq x \leq \frac{2}{3}$

  \item $\frac{5x + 4}{x - 11} < \frac{5x - 7}{x + 13} \\
  \frac{5x + 4}{x - 11} - \frac{5x - 7}{x + 13} < 0 \\
  \frac{(5x + 4)(x + 13) - (5x - 7)(x - 11)}{(x - 11)(x + 13)} < 0 \\
  \frac{5x^2 + 65x + 4x + 52 - 5x^2 + 55x + 7x - 77}{(x - 11)(x + 13)} < 0 \\
  \frac{121x - 25}{(x - 11)(x + 13)} < 0 \\
  \text{Critical numbers:} \\
  121x - 25 = 0 \\
  x = \frac{25}{121} \\
  x - 11 = 0 \\
  x = 11 \\
  x + 13 = 0 \\
  x = -13$ \\
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Intervals & Test value x & 121x - 25 & x - 11 & x + 13 & $\frac{121x - 25}{(x - 11)(x + 13)}$ \\
    \hline
    $x < -13$ & -14 & - & - & - & - \\
    \hline
    $-13 < x < \frac{25}{121}$ & 0 & - & - & + & + \\
    \hline
    $ \frac{25}{121} < x < 11$ & 10 & + & - & + & - \\
    \hline
    $x > 11$ & 12 & + & + & + & + \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} \\
  \\
  Therefore, the solution is $(-\infty,-13)\cup(\frac{25}{121},11)$.

  \item $(3 + x)(5 + x)(7 + x) = 693 \\
  (15 + 3x + 5x + x^2)(7 + x) = 693 \\
  105 + 15x + 56x + 8x^2 + 7x^2 + x^3 - 693 = 0 \\
  x^3 + 15x^2 + 71x - 588 = 0 \\
  \because 4^3 + 15(4)^2 + 71(4) - 588 = 0 \\
  \therefore x - 4$ is a factor. \\
  Devide $x^3 + 15x^2 + 71x - 588$ by x - 4: \\
  $(x - 4)(x^2 + 19x + 127) = 0 \\
  \because 19^2 - (4)(1)(127) < 0 \\
  \therefore x^2 + 19x + 127 = 0$ has no real solution. \\
  When x - 4 = 0, x = 4 \\
  The value of x is 4 will produce a box with a volume of 693 cm^3.

  \item Let x represent the width in meters. \\
  $(3x + 1)(2x - 5)x \geq 8436 \\
  6x^3 - 13x^2 - 5x - 8436 \geq 0 \\
  \because 6(12)^3 - 13(12)^2 - 5(12) - 8436 = 0 \\
  \therefore x - 12$ is a factor. \\
  Devide $6x^3 - 13x^2 - 5x - 8436$ by x - 12: \\
  $(x - 12)(6x^2 + 59x + 703) \geq 0 $\\
  Critical number: \\
  $\because 59^2 - (4)(6)(703) < 0 \\
  \therefore 6x^2 + 59x + 703 = 0$ has no real solution. \\
  When x - 12 = 0, x = 12 \\
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Intervals & Test value x & x - 12 & 6x^2 + 59x + 703 & (x - 12)(6x^2 + 59x + 703) \\
    \hline
    $x < 12$ & 11 & - & + & - \\
    \hline
    $x > 12$ & 13 & + & + & + \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} \\
  $D = \{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\geq12\} \\
  3(12) + 1  = 37 \\
  2(12) - 5 = 19 \\$
  When the length is greater or equal to 37 m, the height is greater or equal to 19 m, and the width is greater or equal to 12 m, the volume of the container is at least 8436 m^3.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: All the other items align like the 6th except the 7th item.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in your document, so in fact it doesn't compile. That's why in the output (which you shouldn't trust anyway because there are errors) the last item of the enumeration is not correctly aligned.

- On line 122, you wrote `cm^3` in text mode, but the exponent written with `^3` must be in math mode. To typeset units, the best way is to use [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx): you could simply replace `cm^3` with `\unit{cm^3}`.
- On line 137, there are polynomials with exponents in text mode. That should be in math mode.
- On line 147, you wrote `m^3` in text mode, so the same error occurs than with `cm^3`.

Here's a corrected version of your example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{Unit 1 Assessment, Part 2}
\date{May 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
  \item x - intercepts of the quadratic function $f(x)=-x^{2}+7x-6$ is at: \\
  $0 = -x^{2} + 7x - 6 = (x - 1)(-x + 6) \\
  x = 1,x = 6$ \\
  The vertical asymptotes of the reciprocal function $g(x)=\frac{1}{-x^{2}+7x-6}$: \\
  $x = 1,x = 6$ \\
  \\
  The horizontal asymptote of the reciprocal is y = 0  since all reciprocal functions have a horizontal asymptote at y = 0. \\
  \\
  The interval of increase of the quadratic function is $(-\infty,3.5)$, and the interval of decrease of the quadratic function is $(3.5,\infty)$. Therefore, the interval of decrease of the reciprocal function is $(-\infty,1)\cup(1,3.5)$, and the interval of increase of the reciprocal function is $(3.5,6)\cup(6,\infty)$.\\
  \\
  The quadratic function has a maximum point at x = 3.5, therefore the reciprocal has a minimum point at x = 3.5. \\
  \\
  The positive interval of the quadratic function is (1,6), and the negative interval of the quadratic function is $(-\infty,1)\cup(6,\infty)$. Therefore, the positive interval of the reciprocal function is (1,6), and the negative interval of the quadratic function is $(-\infty,1)\cup(6,\infty)$.\\
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Graph: $f(x)=-x^{2}+7x-6$ \& $g(x)=\frac{1}{-x^{2}+7x-6}$.}
  \end{figure}

  \item \begin{enumerate}
    \item $f(x) = \frac{-2x - 5}{3x + 18}$
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          Vertical asymptotes & Horizontal asymptotes & x - intercept & y - intercept & Domain \\
          \hline
          x = -6 & $y =  -\frac{2}{3}$ & $(-\frac{5}{2},0)$ & $(0,-\frac{5}{18})$ & $D = \{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\neq-6\}$ \\
          \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Graph: $f(x) = \frac{-2x - 5}{3x + 18}$.}
    \end{figure}

    \item Positive interval: $(-6,-2.5)$ \\
     Negative intervals: $(-\infty,-6)\cup(-2.5,\infty)$
  \end{enumerate}

  \item Find the real roots of the following rational equations.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\frac{-7x}{9x + 11} - 12 = \frac{1}{x} \\
    \frac{-7x}{9x + 11} = \frac{1 + 12x}{x} \\
    (-7x)(x) = (9x + 11)(1 + 12x) \\
    -7x^2 = 9x + 108x^2 + 11 + 132x \\
    115x^2 + 141x + 11 = 0 \\
    x = \frac{-141\pm\sqrt{141^2 - (4)(115)(11)}}{(2)(115)} \\
    x \approx -0.08,x \approx -1.14$

    \item $\frac{x - 1}{x + 2} = \frac{3x + 8}{5x - 1} \\
    (x - 1)(5x - 1) = (x + 2)(3x + 8) \\
    5x^2 - x - 5x + 1 = 3x^2 + 8x + 6x + 16 \\
    2x^2 - 20x - 15 = 0 \\
    x = \frac{-(-20)\pm\sqrt{(-20)^2 - (4)(2)(-15)}}{(2)(2)} \\
    x = \frac{10\pm\sqrt{130}}{2}$
  \end{enumerate}

  \item $8x - 3 \leq 2x+1 \leq 17x - 8 \\
  8x - 3 \leq 2x+1 \\
  6x \leq 4 \\
  x \leq \frac{2}{3} \\
  2x+1 \leq 17x - 8 \\
  9 \leq 15x \\
  x \geq \frac{3}{5} \\
  \frac{3}{5} \leq x \leq \frac{2}{3}$

  \item $\frac{5x + 4}{x - 11} < \frac{5x - 7}{x + 13} \\
  \frac{5x + 4}{x - 11} - \frac{5x - 7}{x + 13} < 0 \\
  \frac{(5x + 4)(x + 13) - (5x - 7)(x - 11)}{(x - 11)(x + 13)} < 0 \\
  \frac{5x^2 + 65x + 4x + 52 - 5x^2 + 55x + 7x - 77}{(x - 11)(x + 13)} < 0 \\
  \frac{121x - 25}{(x - 11)(x + 13)} < 0 \\
  \text{Critical numbers:} \\
  121x - 25 = 0 \\
  x = \frac{25}{121} \\
  x - 11 = 0 \\
  x = 11 \\
  x + 13 = 0 \\
  x = -13$ \\
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Intervals & Test value x & 121x - 25 & x - 11 & x + 13 & $\frac{121x - 25}{(x - 11)(x + 13)}$ \\
    \hline
    $x < -13$ & -14 & - & - & - & - \\
    \hline
    $-13 < x < \frac{25}{121}$ & 0 & - & - & + & + \\
    \hline
    $ \frac{25}{121} < x < 11$ & 10 & + & - & + & - \\
    \hline
    $x > 11$ & 12 & + & + & + & + \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} \\
  \\
  Therefore, the solution is $(-\infty,-13)\cup(\frac{25}{121},11)$.

  \item $(3 + x)(5 + x)(7 + x) = 693 \\
  (15 + 3x + 5x + x^2)(7 + x) = 693 \\
  105 + 15x + 56x + 8x^2 + 7x^2 + x^3 - 693 = 0 \\
  x^3 + 15x^2 + 71x - 588 = 0 \\
  \because 4^3 + 15(4)^2 + 71(4) - 588 = 0 \\
  \therefore x - 4$ is a factor. \\
  Devide $x^3 + 15x^2 + 71x - 588$ by x - 4: \\
  $(x - 4)(x^2 + 19x + 127) = 0 \\
  \because 19^2 - (4)(1)(127) < 0 \\
  \therefore x^2 + 19x + 127 = 0$ has no real solution. \\
  When x - 4 = 0, x = 4 \\
  The value of x is 4 will produce a box with a volume of 693 \unit{cm^3}.

  \item Let x represent the width in meters. \\
  $(3x + 1)(2x - 5)x \geq 8436 \\
  6x^3 - 13x^2 - 5x - 8436 \geq 0 \\
  \because 6(12)^3 - 13(12)^2 - 5(12) - 8436 = 0 \\
  \therefore x - 12$ is a factor. \\
  Devide $6x^3 - 13x^2 - 5x - 8436$ by x - 12: \\
  $(x - 12)(6x^2 + 59x + 703) \geq 0 $\\
  Critical number: \\
  $\because 59^2 - (4)(6)(703) < 0 \\
  \therefore 6x^2 + 59x + 703 = 0$ has no real solution. \\
  When x - 12 = 0, x = 12 \\
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Intervals & Test value x & x - 12 & $6x^2 + 59x + 703$ & $(x - 12)(6x^2 + 59x + 703)$ \\
    \hline
    $x < 12$ & 11 & - & + & - \\
    \hline
    $x > 12$ & 13 & + & + & + \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} \\
  $D = \{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\geq12\} \\
  3(12) + 1  = 37 \\
  2(12) - 5 = 19 \\$
  When the length is greater or equal to 37 m, the height is greater or equal to 19 m, and the width is greater or equal to 12 m, the volume of the container is at least 8436 \unit{m^3}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Now, it does compile, and the last item of the enumeration is correctly aligned in the output.

[image]

I think I should also point out that there are still typographical errors in your document, even if they don't result in LaTeX errors. Here are two suggestions.

- `x` is sometimes written in text mode when it is intended to be a mathematical variable, for example on the first line of the item 7 in the enumeration. When "x" denotes a mathematical quantity, it should always be written in math mode.
- Many of the lines with algebraic manipulations and other mathematical content would be far easier to read if you used display math environments (for example `equation`, `align` or `gather`) to write them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is cause by that m^3 in the seventh item. That's an error; typing `m^3` in order to get m cubed only works in math mode. Use `m\textsuperscript{3}` instead.